# PDF reader with navigation from/to references

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a PDF reader which automatically links in-text citations, in square brackets, to the corresponding references, giving the option to click on the in-text citation to go to the reference and then go back. If it doesn't exist, I can settle for a PDF reader which has good history navigation. In Evince, forward and back buttons are grayed out, and Okular's navigation isn't accurate, usually taking 3-4 steps to go back to the page where I was, even though if I scroll down quickly using one mouse click. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Foxit reader? I tried Evince, Okular and Foxit. I finally settled for using Evince as my default and Okular when I have to do many different annotations. Foxit was slow to start, but is feature-rich.